# Separation of a compact, convex set in $M_n$ and a point not in that compact convex set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a compact, convex set in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $X\notin\mathcal{K}$. Then show that there exist $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ and $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t.
$$e^{i\theta}\mathcal{K}\subseteq\{Y\in M_n(\mathbb{C}): Y+Y^*\leq \mu\}$$ and
$$ e^{i\theta}X+e^{-i\theta}X^*>\mu.$$
where $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the collection of $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries.

---

Comments: I can see this whenever $n=1$ i.e. whenever $\mathcal{K}$ is a compact, convex set in $\mathbb{C}$. But I am not getting any clue to prove the general statement.

Any comment is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you compare matrices and real numbers?

Comment: @PaulFrost Usually, $\mu = \mu I$, and $A>B$ for matrices just means $A-B$ is a positive operator.

Comment: @PaulFrost I mean $\mu=mu I$. If we identify $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$, then we can separate it by hyperplane. But the problem is, I couldn't show that hyperplane would look like the required form upto rotation. That is not the problem for $n=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Let
$$
\mathcal K=\operatorname{conv}\left\{\begin{bmatrix} -1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1-2t&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}:\ t\in[0,1]\right\},\ \ \ \ \ X=I_2.
$$
The first requirement is that 
$$
\mu\geq e^{i\theta}\begin{bmatrix} 1-2t&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+e^{-i\theta}\begin{bmatrix} 1-2t&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2(1-2t)\cos\theta&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Taking $t=0$, a necessary condition on $\theta$ is that 
$$\tag1
\cos\theta\leq\frac\mu2.
$$
The second requirement is that 
$$
\mu<e^{i\theta} I_2+e^{-i\theta}I_2=2\cos\theta I_2,
$$
so 
$$\tag2
\cos\theta>\frac\mu2.
$$
Conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ together are impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What will happen if we replace $\mu$ by selfadjoint matrix $A\in M_n$ in the question? Will it be still false? I can see it does at least in your example given in the answer.